# Unexplainable 16MB malloc in cocos2d app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a cocos2d based app and I am now testing it against the Allocations Tool to check whether some leakage is present. I have noticed there are instants at which a malloc of 16 MB occurs and I can actually not say why. I guess it is something related to the cocos framework but I am not sure of it.

Have you ever experienced the same behaviour? Sometimes the app crashes because of this during the tests.

Thank you in advance

Andrea

Some Futher Details

It seems the problem is related to the way cocos caches sprites. I am using zwoptex texture atlas. Here is the call stack

```
+[CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:capacity:] CCSpriteSheet.m:69 
-[CCSpriteSheet initWithFile:capacity:] CCSpriteSheet.m:104 
-[CCTextureCache addImage:] CCTextureCache.m:243 
-[CCTexture2D(Image) initWithImage:] CCTexture2D.m:207 
-[CCTexture2D(Image) initPremultipliedATextureWithImage:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:]
```

In that point of the execution I am actually loading the largest sprite I have. It is about 900KB. While the others are very little . Am I using cocos in the wrong way?. 
For example are there parameters aimed at reducing such peaks. 
However I would expect that once cached the image would not be loaded any time I need it. Instead I experience new spikes any time I do not use such sprite for some time. 
I then guessed the cache would not be cleared if I reteined the image but despite of the fact I retain it the malloc still occurs.

I would also like to know why the application RAM footprint changes from 3MB to 80MB when running on the simulator instead of the device

Comment: What version of cocos2d do you using?

Comment: Do you get a call stack on the call to `malloc` when it's trying to allocate 16 MB?

Comment: if you are using simulator, it is a common issue with simulator.. If i test on device then wont have it..

Comment: Ok i am running it on the simulator and the situation is fairly different. When on the device the average occupied memory is 3MB while on the simulator it is 80MB (most of them are malloc). Moreover if I run with the Allocations tool it is very slow and crashes almost all the times. Instead on the target is faster and I only see some allocation peaks of 16Mb that are immediately released.

Comment: wow... make sure you release all allocations...

Comment: mmhhh I am pretty sure almost all the allocations are correctly released since: I always use the [CCnode node] method to allocate them (which is an autorelease allocation); the dealloc of each CCNode is overridden to deallocate all the children before invoking the [super dealloc]. I have also added NSLog in the deallocation to check from the console my items are correctly released. And in fact that is what i can verify with the Allocations tool. However I can still see sometimes 16MB are allocated (by means of malloc), and quickly released when running on the device but I can'tunderstand why

Comment: Moreover the average RAM footprint is of 3MB when running on the device while it is of 80 MB while running on the simulator and this does not make any sense to me. Have you ever experienced something like this with cocos2d?

Comment: Instruments *will* record the call stack for these allocations - no need to suppose =)

Comment: why not upgrade to the latest cocos2d-iphone version (1.0.0-beta as of writing)?

Comment: @Justin I am currently using the Allocations instrument? How can I check the call stack of the malloc it reports?

Comment: 1) run your program using Allocations tool 
2) select the Allocations track 
3) click the left-most popup above the outline view (may say 'Statistics'), and select 'Objects List' 
4) locate your offending allocation and select it 
5) enable `View > Extended Detail` 
6) the stack trace appears in the extended detail view

Comment: @Justin thank you
here is the call stack. It seems the problem is related to the way cocos caches sprites. I am using zwoptex texture atlas. Is there something I need to know about it? 

+[CCSpriteSheet spriteSheetWithFile:capacity:] CCSpriteSheet.m:69
 -[CCSpriteSheet initWithFile:capacity:] CCSpriteSheet.m:104
 -[CCTextureCache addImage:] CCTextureCache.m:243
 -[CCTexture2D(Image) initWithImage:] CCTexture2D.m:207
 -[CCTexture2D(Image) initPremultipliedATextureWithImage:pixelsWide:pixelsHigh:] CCTexture2D.m:254

Comment: @A-Sindico you're welcome. idk the answer to this question; i don't use cocos2d. are you loading a large image at this point, or many images? does the allocation seem reasonable, or is the caching simply too greedy? if it's a 16MB spike, your app is killed, and the image(s) is a reasonable size, i'd expect the maintainer of cocos2d wouldn't mind being informed of the issue, and resolving it. if it's open source and the community is often posts patches, then maybe you could patch it? there may also be parameters (e.g., quality) which  may reduce the peak memusage, without visible side-effects.

Comment: In that point of the execution I am actually loading the largest sprite I have. It is about 900KB. While the others are very little . My question was indeed about the possibility i was using cocos in the wrong way. For example wheter there are parameters reducing such peaks. However I would expect that once cached the image would not be loaded any time I need it. Instead I experience new spike if I do not use it for some time. I then guessed the cache would not be cleared if I reteined the image but despite of the fact I retain it the malloc occurs.

Comment: Moreover I would also like to know why the application footprint change from 3MB to 80MB when running on the simulator instead of the device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I guess I can answer my question

I found this method in the app delegate automatically generated when a new cocos2d project is created

```
-(void)applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] purgeCachedData];
}
```

It seems therefore that as soon as the app receives a memory warning the cache is purged. So When I instantiate my 900KB sprite the first time 16MB are allocated (still very strange indeed) and when some times during the execution a memory warning is thrown the cache is purged and it has to load it again. Does it make any sense to you?

Anyway I have commented it and the game seems faster, obviously I have to check very well there are no memory leakages but I am actually pretty sure of it

Comment: more refinement of my answer: the memory spike depends on the size of the png you're using for your sprites.

Answer (score 1):

I had experienced the same when I had using the iSimulate(to register accelerometer data and multi-touch(>2) and transfer to the iSimulator).